# Change background color of pdf

Tags: pdf, adobe

Is there a way to change the background color of a scanned PDF file?
My PDF show a few black lines, and I am trying to remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably easily change it with a PDF Editor. There are a few open source ones out there, check out this page http://www.cogniview.com/convert-pdf-to-excel/post/pdf-editing-creation-50-open-sourcefree-alternatives-to-adobe-acrobat/

Answer (score 10):

**vector** background color (different from **scanned image background color** that is raster) in pdf is determined by this snippet of code inside a pdf, placed between

**stream**

and

**endstream**

tags

```sh
/GS1 gs    
1.000 1.000 1.000 rg    
0.00 841.00 m    
595.25 841.00 l    
595.25 -0.85 l    
0.00 -0.85 l    
0.00 841.00 l    
h    
f
```

in context inside a pdf:

```sh
stream    
/GS1 gs    
1.000 1.000 1.000 rg    
0.00 841.00 m    
595.25 841.00 l    
595.25 -0.85 l    
0.00 -0.85 l    
0.00 841.00 l    
h    
f    
endstream
```

**1.000 1.000 1.000** means = **white**

**1.000 0.000 0.000** means = **red**

**1.000 0.749 0.792** means **pink** and so on...

see these three pdf: (red, pink and white)

http://ge.tt/9ZavuZI

you can obtain these values directly from **sodipodi** color selector or, if you have a graphic software that indicates RGB color values from 0 to 255 you simply apply the proportion

**1:255=x:color you selected**

for instance: let say you have this RGB triplet: **30,144,255**

[image: 30,144,255 rgb image]

to know correspondent values in order to insert in code snippet to change pdf background color, you do:

> **1:255=x:30 = 30/255 = 0.117 (approximated to first three decimals)**
>
> **1:255=x:144 = 144/255 = 0.564 (approximated to first three decimals)**
>
> **1:255=x:255 = 255/255 = 1**

so you insert, in pdf source code, between **stream** and **endstream** tags:

```sh
stream    
/GS1 gs    
0.117 0.564 1.000 rg    
0.00 841.00 m    
595.25 841.00 l    
595.25 -0.85 l    
0.00 -0.85 l    
0.00 841.00 l    
h    
f    
endstream
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Where do I change the background page color or remove the background entirely and have a transparent pdf background?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that on scanned documents, you cannot use the things shown in the previous answers. Try pdftocolor, a PDF color conversion tool 100%free:

http://www.pdftocolor.com