# Is it possible to remove the background of a text block in pdf using ghostscript

Tags: pdf, tiff, ghostscript

I am trying to convert a pdf into tif using ghost script.  Is it possible to remove the background (grey color) of a text block (back font color) in a pdf using ghost script? I would like to replace the grey background to white.

Appreciate your help!!

Comment: this seems a question similar to this I already answered

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856521/change-background-color-of-pdf/10869208#10869208

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll get a generic solution to your problem because there are many different ways such a background may be coded in your PDF and there is no sure way to distinguish such a background from a rectangular form of some vector image.

PDF essentially offers a set of tools for positioning glyphs and vector graphics in some rectangle (page) to display and some additional tools to add some interactivity (e.g. forms). Thus, a colored background in a PDF generally is created by drawing a line along the edge of the area of the background, fill this form with the desired color, and position glyphs and graphics (text and images) atop it. There are other operators, too, which can be used, though, and many variants of their use, and generally the form created is not marked as background.

In the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856521/change-background-color-of-pdf/10869208#10869208) Dingo refers to in his comment a rectangle covering the whole page, actually even a bit more (in case of a fairly common choice of a media box), is drawn (m: move to a corner; 4*l: draw the 4 edge lines; h: close the path; f fill the form).

Thus, please make the PDF in question available for inspection, maybe there is some specific solution for your file.