# PDF contains a lot of white text, how to make it black (partial ghostscript solution already)

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

```
gs -o res.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -c "/osetcolor {/setcolor} bind def /setcolor {pop [0 0 0] osetcolor} def" -f input.pdf
```

this only changes the tables that have white borders, (which is a step in the right direction) I'd like to turn the white font to black.

These are big PDFs so pdfedit is a no. As I said, the above is a partial solution.

The font is already white, the background is white, but the default colours (it's a black colour scheme) on the machine it was made on meant that this wasn't known to the author. So a swap wont work.

Comment: give a look to these answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856521/change-background-color-of-pdf/10869208#10869208, and http://superuser.com/questions/488813/convert-a-colored-pdf-into-a-white-black/488866#488866

Comment: Not sure what that means, I by no means a ghostscript user, that was more-or-less copy and paste of a solution. Also does that actually apply? This is changing a font colour TO black, not swapping (which a lot of my other potential solutions seem to be doing)

Comment: are you sure that the background is settled to white? (i.e. 1 1 1), probably is settled to ***transparent*** that is rendered white in pdf viewer, so you, can looking for all occurrences of RGB TRIPLET (1 1 1) and change to (0 0 0) and you'll have the text in black

Comment: Please, I really don't know ghost-script, could you put that into a command, PDF edit just involved set-colour, so I think the background is white and the font is white.... could you put that into thee form of a command please.

Comment: As long as you're working on the PDF, there are many ways to express white. Can you provide a sample of the PDF?

Comment: If you highlight the text, it's there, the font colour is simply white, I know this because I know the author, I want to force black font colour everywhere, it's not a damaged PDF or some silly effect, it is just white text, white background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the document to post-script and used a function (not sure what they are called) to turn everything black, it worked, I wrote about it in an answer to a different question of mine with a similar title.

Comment: Can you like us to that other question? I can't find it and would love to see your solution, since I've getting the same issue of having white text poorly displayed over a faint black shadow, and would rather it just print black.

Comment: Sorry @MikeS. I no longer contribute here.

Comment: The other questions is probably this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349454/postscript-forcing-a-text-search