# Postscript - forcing a text search

Tags: postscript

Okay, I now "know" postscript, everything makes a lot more sense now.

I've found that if I change the colour though it affects backgrounds in other areas, I now know that sc, SC, cs and CS are procedures:

`/cs { /pdfFillXform exch def dup /pdfFillCS exch def
      setcolorspace } def`

`/CS { /pdfStrokeXform exch def dup /pdfStrokeCS exch def
      setcolorspace } def`

`/sc { pdfLastFill not { pdfFillCS setcolorspace } if
      dup /pdfFill exch def aload pop pdfFillXform setcolor
     /pdfLastFill true def /pdfLastStroke false def } def`

`/SC { pdfLastStroke not { pdfStrokeCS setcolorspace } if
      dup /pdfStroke exch def aload pop pdfStrokeXform setcolor
     /pdfLastStroke true def /pdfLastFill false def } def`

But when I re-colour some parts of it, that seems to affect the background elsewhere! My task is to change all font to black by the way (there's white for some reason ... I really don't get why).

Things like this:

```
-0.925088 TJm
Q
/DeviceGray {} cs
[1] sc
q
[10 0 0 10 0 0] cm
[1 0 0 1 0 0] Tm
0 0 Td
[1 0 0 1 286.875 503.428] Tm
0 0 Td
/F11_0 11.9551 Tf
```

It's that 1 I want to change, I want that to be a 0.

Any ideas I really am not sure what to do now

Source document was a pdf, changed though pdftops

Thanks

Additional:

```
/Tj {
  fCol
  1 index stringwidth pdfTextMat idtransform pop
  sub 1 index length dup 0 ne { div } { pop pop 0 } ifelse
  pdfWordSpacing pdfHorizScaling mul 0 pdfTextMat dtransform 32
  4 3 roll pdfCharSpacing pdfHorizScaling mul add 0
  pdfTextMat dtransform
  6 5 roll Tj1
} def
```

This renders the characters

```
(n) 7.471938 Tj
```

If I can set the colour in that procedure, then pop the colour, I'm set!

How might I do this?

----------------TO PEOPLE OF THE FUTURE---------

```
    /Tj {
        /DeviceGray {} cs
        [0] sc
      fCol
      1 index stringwidth pdfTextMat idtransform pop
      sub 1 index length dup 0 ne { div } { pop pop 0 } ifelse
      pdfWordSpacing pdfHorizScaling mul 0 pdfTextMat dtransform 32
      4 3 roll pdfCharSpacing pdfHorizScaling mul add 0
      pdfTextMat dtransform
      6 5 roll Tj1
    } def
```

That's my fix, I put the device grey part at the bottom, it sets it to black every time this Tj procedure is used (like.... every letter!) and doesn't (seem) to affect anything else.

My white text problem is solved!
http://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf

Worth a read! Postscript's specification!

Comment: Interesting stuff. Welcome to StackOverflow. I think your fix should go in the answer section so it's clear where the question part is. And different PostScript generators use different procsets, so some of your details are tied to the specific program that created this postscript code; it'd be good to say what that program is. It's be great to have a link to the complete file, too. Again, welcome to the site. +1 to get you going.

Comment: wont gsave/grestore do what you want?