# Inverting PDF colors (negative) using Perl PDF::API2

Tags: perl, pdf

Like from title I'm trying to write a script that inverts the colors of a bunch of PDF, by using Perl and PDF::API2.
I'm not very familiar with perl, I've modified a brief script I found here on stackoverflow, from this post, with the help of chatGPT

[how to change all colours in a PDF to their respective complimentary colours; how to make a PDF negative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584228/how-to-change-all-colours-in-a-pdf-to-their-respective-complimentary-colours-ho)

The code I've come to is the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use PDF::API2;
use PDF::API2::Basic::PDF::Utils;

my $dirname = '.';
my $filename;
opendir(DIR, $dirname) or die "Could not open $dirname\n";

mkdir("inverted") unless -d "inverted";

while ($filename = readdir(DIR)) {
  print("$filename\n");
  next unless $filename =~ /\.pdf$/; # Skip files that are not PDFs
  my $pdf = PDF::API2->open($filename);

  for my $n (1..$pdf->pages()) {
    my $p = $pdf->openpage($n);

    $p->{Group} = PDFDict();
    $p->{Group}->{CS} = PDFName('DeviceRGB');
    $p->{Group}->{S} = PDFName('Transparency');

    my $gfx = $p->gfx(1);  # prepend
    $gfx->fillcolor('white');
    $gfx->rect($p->mediabox());
    $gfx->fill();

    $gfx = $p->gfx();  # append
    $gfx->egstate($pdf->egstate->blendmode('Difference'));
    $gfx->fillcolor('white');
    $gfx->rect($p->mediabox());
    $gfx->fill();
  }
  $pdf->saveas("inverted/$filename");
}

closedir(DIR);
```

It seems to partially work sometimes, some pages are correctly inverted; however sometimes the first half of the page is not inverted, it remains white, like in this pic:

[Page partially inverted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txHFr.png)

I'd like to fix this, I'd really need a simple script that perform this job, I've also written a script that after that join all the pdf files from multiple files into a single PDF. If anyone has an idea on how to fix it I'll be grateful, I could also upload the result on github if anyone needs this (it's a question has been asked other times too, but I haven't found a script nor in python or other languages that performs this work well, except for a couple of scripts that relies on docker and nodejs in order to install them)

- I've tried working with chatGPT to fix the issue, but it has no idea on how to do this (yes, I know, I shouldn't rely on it, but this is the first time I use Perl)

Comment: *"sometimes the first half of the page is not inverted, it remains white, like in this pic"* : Can you upload the sample PDF file (before it is converted) somewhere? Then we can try to reproduce.

Comment: Sure, this is the original pdf file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a0q4099r676bq48/01a-1601_testi_scritti_original.pdf?dl=0

This is the inverted version:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ydkadia79p1mhw4/01a-1601_testi_scritti_inverted.pdf?dl=0

Comment: PS I've just read the policy of stack overflow on chatGPT, wasn't aware of that. Obviously I've used it only for minor modification of the code, the source is from the original post I've linked. The content of the code isn't generated from the ground up using it, it's just modified from the original answer in order to take as input only pdf files in the folder, and put all the inverted files into a folder called "inverted" (so I can merge all the pdf files later)

Comment: Seems like the problem could be this line: https://github.com/ssimms/pdfapi2/blob/master/lib/PDF/API2.pm#L1270 it sets the rotation of the page to zero but the actual rotation of the example file is 270 degrees, I think this could cause the inverted page to be rotated incorrectly. I will check closer later when I have more time.

Comment: Thank you, really
Let me know when you find out if that's the problem (and what I can do to fix it in my script, given that I would need to modify the behavior of the library if the error is in there

Answer (score 1):

I am debugging this and am confident it has to do with rotation of the pages but I do not understand the details of the problem yet. However, I have this workaround for the test file:

- Rotate it 90 degrees with [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/), then apply the perl script, then rotate it back 90 degrees with pdftk:

  ```
  $ pdftk test.pdf cat 1-endLeft output test2.pdf
  $ # run perl script to invert the colors in test2.pdf
  $ pdftk test2.pdf cat 1-endRight output test3.pdf
  ```

After this `test3.pdf` seems to be correctly inverted. This workaround might also work for the other files you have.

Comment: Ok, I get it.. I'll try it now
But you think I can apply this to ALL pdf I have? Even the ones that doesn't have the problem? Because I'm processing a bunch of PDF in a single folder, all together.. I don't have a "method" (at least an automatic one) to distinguish between which PDF needs to be rotated before and which one not..